# jQuery ajax POST call to ASP.NET Web Service randomly fails

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, ipad

I'm developing a web site for mobile devices that makes ajax calls using jQuery (v 1.7.2) to an ASP.NET (v 2.0.50727) Web Service.

The call works correctly about 95% of the time, but it will randomly fail, returning a 500 internal server error. It fails on the server side before the first line of code is ever executed (the first line writes to the event log).

I haven't seen the call fail using a desktop browser that I remember, but I've seen it fail enough using an iPad. I added

```
<browserCaps userAgentCacheKeyLength="256">
```

to the Web Service's web.config file, but that hasn't helped.

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: serverURL + "/getImage",
  data: '{"formURL":"' + url + '", "rowNumber":"'+rowNumber+'"}',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (msg,textStatus, jqXHR) {
    ...
  }, error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    ...
  }
}).done(function(){
  console.log("getImage call is done");
});
```

Example data passed to the web service:

```
'{"formURL":"fileName.xml", "rowNumber":"1"}'
```

c#

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string getImage(string formURL, string rowNumber) {
  log("Retrieving image of form " + formURL);
  string image = "";
  string username = /*retrieve username*/;
  string password = /*retrieve password*/;
  if (username != null && username != "") {
    image = /*code to retrieve the image*/;
  }
  return image;
}

private void log(string message) {
  EvLog.WriteToEventLog(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM:dd:yyyy H:mm:ss:fff") + Environment.NewLine + message, 10);
}
```

The only thing I've found that has slightly helped me, is when the call fails because the response headers from the Web Service contain "jsonerror: true" though I haven't been able to pinpoint why it would randomly fail.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could it be that when it fails to send the data up it somehow contains invalid JSON? Maybe some invalid characters in the filename or the rownumber? Add the data into a variable i.e: `var data = '{"formURL":"' + url + '", "rowNumber":"'+rowNumber+'"}'`  then add a `console.log(data)` before the ajax call which should show you the data you are about to send in the conole output window of your browser debugging tool. Debuggin tools are build-in to Chrome and IE (F12 hotkey I think) and for FF you need to istall the FireBug AddOn.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you can try messing with another setting in the ajax call `traditional: true`. We found that to work for posting JSON but we are using ASP.NET MVC3, but still worth a try. `traditional: true` will cause "shallow" serialization. See here for more details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: I have log statements in before the ajax call is made to see what is being sent, and it will fail randomly on the same data set (multiple calls using the same data)

Comment: Even with adding `traditional: true` I have since seen it fail

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it truly is a JSON error, my first thought is that the data being passed into the parameters is incorrect.

The following line is quoting the contents of variables, which I assume is being loaded from somewhere else in the code:

`data: '{"formURL":"' + url + '", "rowNumber":"'+rowNumber+'"}',`

Assuming you are already making sure rowNumber is an integer value and wouldn't break it, the likelihood is that the 'url' variable is breaking your JSON format.  The easiest way this could happen is if you had an unescaped quote in the filename, especially if it's closing your parameter values earlier than expected when it gets concatenated.

There's always the possibility of the characters not being valid for the charset.  Do you have an example data that triggers the failure?  The example provided looks nice and clean, so I'm assuming it wasn't one of the error cases.

Comment: Both parameters on the server side are strings but escaped characters sounds definelty something that could mess up the bindings.

Comment: The odd thing is that the call using the same data will work roughly 9/10 times then fail once, then start working again.
But an example of data being submitted is
`{"formXML":"20120807114859.xml", "rowNumber":"5"}`

Comment: If your server throws Internal Server Error 500, check the error log to get an idea of what causes it.

Comment: I've tried looking through the logs, can't say I found error logs, but the logs I did see only told me what I knew -- that the call is returning status code 500

Answer (score 0):

Don't build your data in this way

`data: '{"formURL":"' + url + '", "rowNumber":"'+rowNumber+'"}',`

It can cause malformed JSON string.

Instead of this stringify your JavaScript object using JSON.stringify method:

`data: JSON.stringify({formUrl: url, rowNumber: rowNumber}),`

JSON.stringify will make all job for you to represent your object as valid JSON string.

Comment: testing this now to see if it is fixed

Comment: Anyway put your server code into try-catch block and write a log on uncaught errors to get an idea of what happens (sure if you have no such mechanism yet).

Comment: Even with the change to JSON.stringify, it is still randomly failing. The first attempt after changing it failed, but calls after that have worked.

Comment: 1. Add AJAX error handler on client side `$.ajax(/*...*/).error(function(data){/* */});`
2. Make sure you're handling uncaught server-side errors and storing an information about them as I've already mentioned.
Obviously you need to perform these steps to be able to debug the flow properly.

Comment: I do have error handling on the client side. I have added a try-catch to the server side, but the first line of code in the server-side method is never even called...so the try catch isn't too helpful. The call fails immediately without ever doing anything

Comment: So add try-catch somewhere in call stack before this method invocation, e.g. in main entry point.